# Laravel loading validation errors on page load, Forms submit without any issue

Tags: validation, error-handling, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2 running locally on MAMP and am experiencing the same issue on an AWS instance with Ubuntu 14 PHP 5.9.

I have come across a very strange and frustrating issue on my Laravel project.

On page load, every form shows a validation error. Has errors reports true while the errors array is empty.

I for the life of me can I can not figure out how to debug this problem. I have Sentry installed and works fine, nothing is reported to Sentry, nothing is being logged.

I tried removing Sentry as it was the last thing added ( Raven was marked as Deprecated ).

I am close to simply removing the server side validation and just letting JavaScript handle it.

I have gone back two months in history and the issue still exists. This seems completely unlikely as we have a lot of eyes on the site.

Any suggestions on how to dig further into this or if you have any ideas would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

```
{{ var_dump($errors->has()) }} <!-- true -->
{{ var_dump($errors->all()) }} <!-- none -->

@if ($errors->has())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <strong>Whoops! Something went wrong!</strong>
        <br><br>
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
    </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Did you upgrade from an oldest version of laravel ?

Comment: Try to add all your web routes to a route group and apply the web middleware to them like this `Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function() {
    // Place all your web routes here...
});`

Comment: @Maraboc No, I have been on 5.2 for since the start of this project. I did change the view partial to use `@if (count($errors) > 0)` from `@if ($errors->has())`.  I also run form submissions through a controller that cleans up and validates the content before it's submitted to a different API. If we do catch errors we redirect back with them.  Did something change in regards to using `['middleware' => 'web']` A lot of the answers I found mentioned it.

Comment: Because the `errors` varialbe is not initialised in the global middeleware any more, for the laravel 5.2 it's initialised in the `web` middeleware.

Comment: @Maraboc I have `ShareErrorsFromSession::class` in my HTTPKernel Middleware if that helps.  

I'm just confused why it was working and then was not working.  `$errors->has()` should not return true if the variable was not set.  It really should not have worked at all. My problem should have been, I can't get the errors to show.    

`count($errors) > 0` did fix my problem and validation still correctly works.

Thanks for the tips though.

Answer (score 0):

From BrandonSurowiec on Github:

> It was broken due to some code refactoring in one of the last two releases, then was fixed in this commit: #14409
>
> So the next release 5.2.42 should restore the expected behavior. You can view issue #14396 for more information.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14396

The solution for now was to use `@if($errors->count())`